# Life after linear algebra and multivariate calculus

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, statistics

I have been following Strang's Linear Algebra course, and found it quite challenging. My goal, however, is to learn application of linear algebra and calculus in applied statistics (regression, linear mixed models, structural equation modeling, et cetera). I want to understand the math behind these techniques. Some people suggest learning abstract algebra after linear algebra. However, after trying one to two lectures by Benedict Gross (on youtube), I find that it is totally not for me - I was lost very soon about what he talked about. In addition, I am unsure if abstract algebra is very useful to applied statistics. Therefore, I am unsure what I should learn after linear algebra and calculus, and I preferably want to learn something with online videos (as self-learning stats can be quite difficult).

Comment: So... what's your question?

Comment: If strang's book is confusing you, attempting to learn abstract algebra will largely be a waste of time.  I would start by reading a couple books on statistics.  But perhaps you are looking for non-statistics books to read?  Then you want an introductory book on mathematical analysis.  This will help you gain the skills you need to be able to read more advanced material, and it'll help your mathematical maturity level as some say.  Sources exist online, on youtube, wherever... just google it.

Comment: You don't need abstract algebra to do statistics and regression.  My favorite intro to Prob/Stats at your level is Larson - you can get a used copy here: https://smile.amazon.com/Introduction-Probability-Theory-Statistical-Inference/dp/0471059099/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1470573201&sr=8-1&keywords=larson+probability

Comment: @Gregory Grant Thanks! I will take a look.

Comment: Suggest you contact someone in your local university statistics department, and ask her what to do.

Comment: One should certainly NOT have to learn abstract algebra in order to understand justifications of statements in linear algebra! (I don't mean that as any disparagement of abstract algebra.) $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One place in statistics where abstract algebra (specically finite fields)  is used is  in the construction of mutually orthogonal latin squares which are used in Design of (statistical) Experiments.  Knowing  linear algebra, matrix, eigenvalues, positive definiteness, generalized inverses is the most important thing. You can safely skip abstract algebra and focus on applications of matrices.  One small book that does this well  is  by Bapat (Linear Algebra and Linear Models?) published by Hindustan Book Agency, New Delhi.

Comment: Thanks! It looks helpful! Other important books/resources on catching up with the stats behind statistical techniques quick? I am familiar with how to actually use these stats without understanding the math behind them.